# Ubuntu 16.04.1: Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!

Tags: ubuntu, kernel

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 and sometimes my PC freezes and prints this message. In order to use the laptop again a forced shutdown using the laptop's power button is required. What are the steps to fix this?

[image]